# Restore My"com.apple.iChat"file

Tags: applescript, message, restore, ichat

I delete"/Users/wangcl/Library/Application Scripts/com. apple. iChat" file before for a long time, And I really need it.Now my imessages cannot perform AppleScript processor, is there a way to restore?

I would be grateful for any help.Thanks!

Model: mac pro
AppleScript: 2.10(194)
Browser: chrome 66.0.3359.117
Operating System: Mac OS X (10.13 Public Beta)

Comment: This appears to be a general computing question, and as written it's not really a question involving programming, and really doesn't belong here. If you have a backup of the file, e.g. a Time Machine backup, then you can restore it from that, or other backup. If you do not have a backup of the file, then you'll need to manually recreate it.

Comment: Very sorry，I haven't backup of Time Machine.

Comment: I tried it.and It's not there

Comment: I tried these ways:
1 , Use "Time Machine" to restore my file;
2 , Restore my computer to be the factory setting;
3 , And add Jabber account.

It all failed.⋯⋯
The second way make me get the "com.apple.ichat"file,but in my messages app ,applescript handle still doesn't show.
There was no problem with another 10.13.4 MacBook.and My computer is MacBook Pro.


Is there any other way?
Thanks!

Comment: OK! I think I've found the answer.

You can look at this : https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/318230/did-apple-remove-the-applescrip t-handler-option-in-macos-high-sierra

Apple removed the feature on OSX10.13.4

"Applescript handler"……

I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK! I think I've found the answer. You can look at this : apple.stackexchange.com/questions/318230/… t-handler-option-in-macos-high-sierra Apple removed the feature on OSX10.13.4 "Applescript handler"…… I don't know why.